# Create jpg or png file from turtle graphics?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, jpeg, python-turtle

I have a little problem with my code, my program in python make a Watch in Turtle. I can make the file in eps format, but not in png or jpg format.
I get following error: `Unable to locate Ghostscript on paths`.

What is going wrong, with my code?

```
def main_ur():
   moveHourHand()
   moveMinuteHand()
   turtle.update()
   fileName = 'test'
   wn.tracer(False)
   wn.tracer(True)
   canvas = wn.getcanvas()
   canvas.postscript(file= fileName+'.eps', width=400, height=500)
   img = Image.open(fileName + '.eps') 
   img.save(fileName + '.png', 'png') 
   wn.exitonclick()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main_ur()
```

Comment: You're getting the error from the `PIL.Image` because it's attempting to convert the `eps` file into an image using the `Ghostscript` program which you do not have installed. There are other ways to do it that don't involve using eps files, if you search for questions related to saving turtle screens as png image files here.

Comment: You could simply screenshot and then crop?

Comment: That work now, i have install Ghostscript on PC.
And added following

from PIL import Image, EpsImagePlugin
EpsImagePlugin.gs_windows_binary = r'C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.54.0\bin\gswin64c'

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Related: [How can I convert canvas content to an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886274/how-can-i-convert-canvas-content-to-an-image/10432892#10432892), [How can I save a Turtle canvas as an image (.png or .jpg)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62048513/how-can-i-save-a-turtle-canvas-as-an-image-png-or-jpg?rq=3), [Convert images drawn by turtle to PNG in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35629520/convert-images-drawn-by-turtle-to-png-in-python) and [Save turtle output as jpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25050156/save-turtle-output-as-jpeg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert canvas content to an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886274/how-can-i-convert-canvas-content-to-an-image)